# Login with mysqli failed

Tags: php, mysqli

i have an Problem with my MySQLi Login Script.

If i try to login, the Page redirects me to an **Blank** Page, with the Data from the form in the URL.

My Code:

**external "connection.php":**

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'user');
$database_user = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

**The Login Script:**

```
$database_user; //Variable -> Database   
$login_mail = $_REQUEST['a_email']; //Email Textbox
$login_pw = hash('sha512',$_REQUEST['a_password']); //Password Textbox

login($login_mail,$login_pw,$database_user);

function login($login_mail,$login_pw,$database_user) {


    $stmt = $database_user->prepare("SELECT * FROM user(email,passwort) VALUES(?,?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$login_mail,$login_pw);
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->fetch_row();



    if($database_user->connect_errno) {
        echo "<h3>Connection Failed</h3>";
        exit();
    }

    $url = $result[7];

    if($result > 0) {
        $_SESSION['your_url'] = $url;
        header('location:../profil.php?user=' . $url);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I forgot to create the Dataset, so the blank site was shown :D 
But now the server shows me an "Servererror 500".

Comment: check whether form `method`  is POST

Comment: i missed that, thanks. But error is still there :/ Need to say that i am working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, maybe there is an configuration error?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user(email,passwort) VALUES(?,?)` that is invalid syntax. RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Blank page means syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($database_user))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I add error_reporting, but it didnt show me an error. only thing i see is "Server error 500" ^^.

Comment: i found the problem. It was nothing with the Code. The Permission from the Server was wrong configured

Comment: Please consider either posting an answer describing how you diagnosed the issue (if you believe it may help others in the future), or delete the question.